# Given v in W, why can we say {u : u in W} = {v + u : u in W} = W?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

For context, I'm going back through a linear algebra textbook, and I got to the problem:

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$. For any $v \in V$, the set $v + W = \{v + w : w \in W \}$ is called the $\bf{coset}$ of $W$ $\bf{containing}$ $v$.
Prove that $v + W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $v \in W$.

My solution for the $\impliedby$ direction goes as follows:

Assume $v \in W$. Then $\forall w \in W$, $v + w \in W$ by closure under vector addition. Then $v + W = \{v + w : w \in W\} = W$, so $v + W$ is equal to $W$ and is therefore a subspace of $V$.

My concern is with justifying that $\{v + w : w \in W\} = \{w : w \in W\}$. It seems dead obvious but I'm not sure exactly how you're allowed to make that switch from $v + w$ to just $w$. I feel like I'm missing something simple, I'd appreciate if someone could point out exactly what it is.

Comment: Hint: write $v,\,w$ in terms of a basis of $W$.

Comment: To be very explicit, you should show that each set is a subset of the other. This means you should show that whenever $w \in W$, we have $v + w \in W$, and also whenever $w \in W$, we can find a $w' \in W$ such that $w = v + w'$. (This is what the answer below does). Both of these steps are very straightforward, so don't worry if it still feels too obvious.

Comment: I couldn't quite see why it was that $w'$ could be any element of $W$ and not just elements from some proper subset of $W$. Correct me if this doesn't work as justification, but I think it worked to set $f: W \to W$, $f(w) = w - v$ and show that $f$ was bijective, thus $f(W) = W$ and $\{w - v : w \in W \} = W$. Thanks for writing out your response, seeing it in sentences helped me quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

$v+w\in W$ so $v+W\subseteq W$. $w=v+(w-v)$ and $w-v\in W$, so $W\subseteq v+W$.